# couchdb GET _replicator database returns 500

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I have a cluster where the _replicator database returns: 
{"error":"nodedown","reason":"progress not possible"}

All other DBs are good, I don't have any replication beyond the cluster itself. I'd like just recreate the _replicator DB in the cluster since there is nothing to lose, how do I go about doing this?

Extra Background: Originally we had setup the cluster separately and started replicating from a single node instance, recently I removed the replication, upgraded the the single instance to v2.2 and added it as part of the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me as well, the _replicator DB was corrupted.
Issue DELETE to /_replicator and then PUT /_replicator to recreate the DB.
Naturally, you will have to recreate the replication jobs.